# CollectionView с отображением предыдущего и следующего элементов

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

Доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста, как, можно реализовать похожую collectionView, где будут видны левая и правая ячейки и при этом корректно работать paging. (Скролл нужен по всей поверхности, игры с clipToBounds не подойдут)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение - взять готовое решение и подстроить под нужды. Например 2 хороших решения под Ваш случай:

[CenteredCollectionView](https://github.com/BenEmdon/CenteredCollectionView)
[UPCarouselFlowLayout](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout)

Легко настроить или изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - сделать свой сабкласс лейаута `UICollectionView`. Правильный пейджинг будет достигаться путём перегрузки определенных методов лэйаута. С таким подходом вы сможете очень гибко настроить коллекцию под свои нужды. Но это, конечно, сложнее и затратное по времени в сравнении с готовыми решениями.